# While loop with if statements does work not but as it is supposed to (Math.random)

Tags: java, random

My programs goal is to at first generate a random number from 1-6 calling that the 'point' then the user is to keep inputting a key to rey-roll the sopposed 'dice', and if that same number is rolled the user should be prompted with the message from the first if statement

However, whenever the next dice is rolled it never rolls onto the point number, and the first if statement printed line prints out randomly. An answer would be much appreciated on how to fix this?

```
import java.io.*;

public class DiceGame1
{
  public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
  {

    String userInput;
    int DiceRoll;
    int exit = 0;


    BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    System.out.println("Hello, this program rolls a dice and outputs the number rolled");

    System.out.println("The number rolled is called the point it will keep rolling untill it");
    System.out.println("hits that point again, press any key to con't");

    userInput = myInput.readLine();

    DiceRoll = (int) (Math.random () *(6-1) + 1);

    System.out.println("The point to match is: " + DiceRoll);
    System.out.println("Press any key to roll again...");
    userInput = myInput.readLine();

    while(exit != 999) {
      int nextRoll = (int) (Math.random () *(6-1) + 1);

      if (nextRoll == DiceRoll)
      {
        System.out.println(" It took the computer _____ tries to reach the point");
      }
      else 
      {
        System.out.println("The roll is : " + nextRoll);
        System.out.println("Press any key to roll again...Or press '999' to exit");
        userInput = myInput.readLine();
      }  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Code would be much appreciated if you want us to help you fix this.

Comment: sorry i just pasted it, my apologies!

Comment: And what exact bad behavior are you seeing?

Comment: Where are you assigning `exit` value? Your while loop will never exit.

Comment: THe roll of the dice of a the integer nextRoll never actually equals DiceRoll , but the line System.out.println("It took the computer...") is printed in random situtations when it is only sopposed to print under the certain circumstances

Comment: That's because you never print out what the roll was when they match...

Comment: How would I do that mellamokb the Wise?

Comment: `System.out.println("The roll is : " + nextRoll);`?  You probably want to do that always, not just inside the `else`.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Using console print statements may not properly tell you what is happening in the program since System.In is not immediate in it's printing. Try using a debugger and evaluate your expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop exit condition is `exit == 999`. But you never assign any value to `exit` in the loop. So it loops endlessly.

In addition, you only print the value of the dice when it's not equal to the first roll. And not when it is. So you got the impression that the first message is printed when it shouldn't.

Comment: Even with that inplace, that does not solve my actual problem.

Comment: So with that in mind, is there a way I could fix it so it would print that line ?

Comment: Yes, print it just as you did in the `else` block. And since you would end up with the exact same instruction in the `if` and in the `else` block, you can just move this instruction before the `if` block. Did you actually write the code, or did you get it from somewhere without understanding it?

Comment: Yes i wrote the code, but this random integer stuff is brand new to me.

Comment: So leave the else block the same, but move the instructions outside of the while loop before the if block?

Comment: Each time the dice rolls, you want to print its value right after. Once this value is printed, you want to compare it with the initial value. Why would you move the print out of the while loop? And why would you leave the else clause is is: it would print the same value twice. Have you understood what if, else and while mean?

Comment: The program works now.. Except i need to input a counter into my while loop, would another integer set to zero work, then simply printing it?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for to do is to always have to roll the dice, even if it is a match. You can accomplish that by removing the print and input to outside of the else clause, as such:

```
  if (nextRoll == DiceRoll)
  {
    System.out.println(" It took the computer _____ tries to reach the point");
  }
  else 
  {
    System.out.println("The roll is : " + nextRoll);
  }  
   System.out.println("Press any key to roll again...Or press '999' to exit");
   userInput = myInput.readLine();
```

Besides, you will never get a DiceRoll or NextRoll that is 6 - `(int) Math.random()*5+1` = (int) (0-.999)*5+1 = (int) (0-4.999)+1 = (int) 1-5.999 = 1-5. The cast to int will round downwards, so you will need `(int) Math.random()*6+1` instead.

Comment: This does not fix the problem, since the first if statement line is still printed randomly